# Android java : rotate image at imageview

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-imageview

I have try out a lot of research to rotate my imageview picture. Still not working .
Bellow have my app screen shoot . I wish to have clockwise rotation. Any idea to do that ?
I have edit the previous code and this is the current code:

```
 imb_rotate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imb_rotate);
        imb_rotate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
                imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                imgView.setImageMatrix(matrix);


            }
        });
```

The following link is the image of my apps:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos?pid=5991339872494743442&oid=114816496239615013742
as you can see the tin are actually horizontal . I wish when I press the rotate button it can become vertical.

Comment: what gallery? app? widget? maybe some picture?

Comment: Do you have any code you could share with us?

Comment: how have you used the matrix class?

Comment: @gkapagunta I'm new in android i try out some example from other website

Comment: @curtisLoew shared. please help me check if `(getResources(R.drawable.ic_coffee))` it call out the ic_coffee and rotate to 45. But I wish the image in image view to be rotate not hard coded.

Comment: @pskink same function like android gallery rotate - select rotate it rotate 90 . the only different is I wish it rotate in my image view

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still have difficulties understating your question. Please edit/update your question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to rotate the image:

```
public class RotateImageView extends ImageView {
    private static Animation mRotation;
    public boolean isAnimating = false;

public RotateImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Init(null);
}

public RotateImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Init(attrs);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public RotateImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Init(attrs);
}

private void Init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    startAnimation();
}

public void startAnimation() {
    if(!isAnimating){
        if (mRotation == null) {
            mRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotate);
            mRotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }
        this.startAnimation(mRotation);
        isAnimating  = true;
    }

}

public void stopAnimation() {
    if (isAnimating){
        mRotation.cancel();
        isAnimating  = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
    if (visibility == GONE || visibility == INVISIBLE) {
        this.clearAnimation();
    } else if (visibility == VISIBLE) {
        this.startAnimation(mRotation);
    }
    super.setVisibility(visibility);
}
}
```

then :

```
 //global var
static RotateImageView rotateimageview ;
 //onCreate() function
rotateimageview = new RotateImageView(getActivity());
 //inside your function(ex. onClickListener())
 rotateimageview.startAnimation();
 //or
 rotateimageview.stopAnimation();
```

your layout.xml :

```
    <yourname.RotateImageView 
        android:id="@+id/rotateimageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimage"
        />
```